# problem in read and write data from a 2D arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, objectoutputstream

i'm new in android development, i'm facing a problem while write the arraylist into the outjectoutputstream write object, seek for help from every expert here.

```
public Items(String task, String date) {
    this.task = task;
    this.date = date; 
}
```

passing value

```
String itementered = edText.getText().toString();                   
String dateentered = tvDate.getText().toString();                    
Items item1 = new Items(itementered, dateentered);        
ArrayList<Items> ItemList = new ArrayList<>();        
ItemList.add(item1);                                   
writeData(ItemList, this);
```

Write data

```
public static void writeData(ArrayList<Items> item, Context context){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos =context.openFileOutput(FILENAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(item);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"i'm facing a problem"* What problem might that be?

Comment: In what way is `ArrayList<Items>` a **2D** arraylist? What is two-dimensional about it?

Comment: i'm getting error on java.io.NotSerializableException when write the object.

Comment: thanks! it's really helpful for a beginner just like me.

Comment: Reading the documentation is really helpful for *all* programmers, beginners as well as fully experienced. The Java Runtime Library is simply too big to memorize it all, so all Java programmers should use it.